# Separating referenced text from own text, a simple example

Tags: citations, plagiarism

Consider this example:

> According to XYZ [1], this is referenced text. This is is also referenced text. Now this is my
>   text in the same paragraph.

It does not tell where the referenced text ends and where my text starts. I understand I can place reference number at the end of line, but is there any other way, like in above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply restructure. You can also employ suitable use of quotes instead of paraphrasing. Or break the paragraph before your own text.

For example,

> in XYX we learn this is referenced text. This is is also referenced text.[1] Now this is my text in the same paragraph.

Or

> According to XYZ [1], this is referenced text. This is is also referenced text.
>
> Now this is my text in a new paragraph.

Or, set off the referenced text in its own paragraph entirely. Or use quoted text, not paraphrased and use formal quote marks.

Or, use a distinguished font for the referenced text. Or, ...

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question, because I am not sure, you want to quote what XXX ref# said. This is done by "quoting".

Else the reader interprets all the the text as your own, and the reference just a justification for it.